# Typescript Error Cannot find name ‘google’

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

if i save the file twice its run, but dont know why
google.maps.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.initMap();
}

initMap(){
    let coords = new google.maps.LatLng(37.992667,-1.1146491);
    let mapOptions: google.maps.MapOtpions= {
        center: coords,
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement,
    mapOptions)


}
```

}

this is the error code...

```
Typescript: C:/ionic/restaurante/IESAljada/src/components/google-map/google-map.ts, line: 22

  L21:  initMap(){
  L22:      let coords = new google.maps.LatLng(37.992667,-1.1146491);
  L23:      let mapOptions: google.maps.MapOtpions= {
```

Answer (score 1):

`google.maps.MapOtpions` looks like a typo. Did you mean [`google.maps.MapOptions`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/21c6ad0a199fc3ea07160e44bd67643f9f6f617b/types/googlemaps/index.d.ts#L61)?

Comment: Yes but the problem still there, now i am using a button with a windows.open('https://www.google.es/maps','_server');

Answer (score 0):

Try this basic example. Declare

> declare var google;

in your typescript file. Like below:

```
declare var google;

@Component( {
    selector: 'page-example',
    templateUrl: 'example.html'
} )
export class GoogleMapExample {
    @ViewChild( 'map' ) mapElement: ElementRef;
    map: any;
    private defaultLat = 56.1304;
    private defaultLng = 106.3468;

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.loadMap();
    }

    private loadMap = () =>{
        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( this.defaultLat, this.defaultLng );
        console.log("latLng====>",latLng);
        let mapOptions = {
            center: latLng,
            zoom: 15,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        }
        this.map = new google.maps.Map( this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions );
    }
}
```

And HTML will be : `<div #map id="map"></div>`

Comment: i just noticed that i am using Ionic , not ionic --v2.  Could that be a problem?

Comment: this is how i start a project : ionic start helloWorld blank
i read that this way create ionic3 project

Comment: If you have recently installed ionic, it will create a project with the latest version. Just check ionic version using ionic --v or ionic -version

Answer (score 0):

Please try the sample code from the [official](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/) docs

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/README.md

Installation

```
$> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps \
  --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="(API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID)" \
  --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="(API_KEY_FOR_IOS)"

$> npm install --save @ionic-native/core@latest @ionic-native/google-maps@latest
```

code

```
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  GoogleMapOptions,
  CameraPosition,
  MarkerOptions,
  Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import { Component } from "@angular/core/";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  map: GoogleMap;
  constructor() { }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
         target: {
           lat: 43.0741904,
           lng: -89.3809802
         },
         zoom: 18,
         tilt: 30
       }
    };

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);

    let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
      title: 'Ionic',
      icon: 'blue',
      animation: 'DROP',
      position: {
        lat: 43.0741904,
        lng: -89.3809802
      }
    });
    marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
      alert('clicked');
    });
  }
}
```